# Querying has-many-though in Laravel

Tags: laravel, has-many-through, querying

My Laravel application has three models

1. Category
2. Subcategory
3. Channels

Category - Subcategory (one category has many subcategories)
Subcategory - Channels (many to many relation)

I have the following relations:

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function subcategories()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }

    public function channels()
    {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Channel','App\Subcategory');
    }
}


class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function Category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function channels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class, 'channel_subcategory', 'channel_id', 'subcategory_id')
->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Channel extends Model
{
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class, 'channel_subcategory', 'channel_id', 'subcategory_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

I have 4 tables:

1. categories
2. subcategories
3. channel_subcategory
4. channels

I want to query all channels inside a category, organized in subcategories. Something like:

```
Category A
    Subcategory A-1
        Channel A-1-1
        Channel A-1-2
    Subcategory A-2
        Channel A-2-1
        Channel A-2-2
```

Given the Category.slug I have made the following Query in the Category Controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = Category::with('subcategories')->where('categories.slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    $channels = $category->channels;
    return view('categories.show')->withCategory($category)->withChannels($channels);
}
```

And I get an error stating:

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 319: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'channels.subcategory_id' in 'on clause'
(SQL: select `channels`.*, `subcategories`.`category_id` 
from `channels` 
inner join `subcategories` on `subcategories`.`id` = `channels`.`subcategory_id` where `subcategories`.`category_id` = 1)
```

Eloquent assumes that there is a one-to-many between channels and subcategories and ignores the pivot table

My questions are:

1. Is there a solution using Eloquent? Many-throught relations with a pivot table in the middle?
2. Using plain MySQL, how just got the list of channels ALL togethere, but I have not idea how to separate them in groups of subcategories. Any help?

**EDIT TO CLARIFY:**

3. I am trying to query through FOUR tables here:
   CATEGORIES, SUBCATEGORIES, CHANNEL_SUBCATEGORY AND CHANNELS
4. I want to find the channels in a Category grouped by subcategories. (channels and subcategories has a many-to-many relation)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your channels table does'nt have a column name subcategory_id but category_id ?

So that you have to tell laravel how to handle your relationship :

In your Category Model:

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Channel','App\Subcategory',
        'category_id', 'subcategory_id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Edit after reply :

Ok then the relationship is not a hasManyThrough, but a belongs to :

```
 public function channels()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel', 'channel_subcategory', 'channel_id','subcategory_id');
 }
```

By default, laravel will search for a category_id foreign_key, but as you rename it subcategory_id you have to specify all the relationship

Comment: my channels table does not have category_id, it also does not have subcategory_id. Because is a Many-to-many-relations. I have a channel_subcategory PIVOT table in which there are are two foreign keys: subcategory_id and channel_id